# hx-get not fire after infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, django, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints, htmx

In each post I have this code :

```
{% if result.has_url %}
    <div hx-get="{% url 'post:load-url-preview' result.pk %}" hx-trigger="revealed">
             
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

In the first pagination, the htmx is firing but after infinite scrolling, it is not firing (I'm using Waypoints Infinite Scroll). I noticed that other jquery too is not working after page > 1.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need a 3rd party infinite scroll library for this? I suggest taking a look at the infinite scroll example on the htmx website https://htmx.org/examples/infinite-scroll/

Comment: I already implemented the infinite scroll before I knew htmx, I'll try to use the htmx one now to see if the problem still exist